# UISegmentedControl divider image not showing up

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` and I am trying to set a divider image.  The image is black and about 2px wide.

```
UIImage *divider = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ZSDivider.png"];
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I didn't want anything fancy for the divider, just a black line for every state, but it isn't showing up at all.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is your divider image the same height as your segmented control? If I recall correctly UISegmentedControl have problems if the divider doesn't match the control height.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that "`divider`" and "`self.segmentedControl`" are not null?

This looks like a great opportunity for error checking:

```
UIImage *divider = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ZSDivider"];
if(divider)
{
    if(self.segmentedControl)
    {
        [self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:divider forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    } else {
        NSLog( @"segmentedControl is NULL");
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"divider image is NULL");
}
```

Comment: No, everything is fine.  The strange thing is the separator finally does show once I have clicked a few segments, but only between the middle and right segments.